# select record before most recent record

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to get the previous record before the last record of something in a table

```
SELECT MAX(BillID), ConsumerID_FK,
SELECT CurrentReading FROM tblReading ORDER BY ReadingID DESC LIMIT 1,1) AS 
'PreviousReading',
CurrentReading 
FROM tblBilling b INNER JOIN tblReading r ON r.ReadingID = b.ReadingID_FK 
INNER JOIN tblconsumer c ON c.ConsumerID = r.ConsumerID_FK
GROUP BY r.ReadingID
```

[image]

returns only the previous record of `ConsumerID_FK=28`. The previous reading of 11 is 21. I want to do this for all of the consumers.

I want it to return the previous reading of each individual consumer.

```
Max(billID)  | ConsumerID_FK  | Previous Reading | CurrentReading
------------------------------------------------------------------
     1       |     11         |      21          |      32  
     2       |     28         |      12          |      16
```

Comment: Sample data will be helpful..

Comment: Also the database version you are using because its very easy using row_number if you are at 3.25.0